Multipling a stochastically bounded variable with an a.s. O(1/n)
Suppose we have random variables $\vert X_n \vert \leq O(1/n)$ a.s., and $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$, where $\Rightarrow$ stands for convergent in distribution. It would be straightforward to get that $X_n Y_n$ converges in probability to $0$.
Is it possible to get $X_n Y_n \to 0$ a.s.? Intuitively $Y_n$ is stochastically bounded and multiplied with something going to $0$ a.s., will it be possible that $X_nY_n$ goes to $0$ on a measure one set?

Let $X_n\equiv \frac 1 n$ and $(Y_n)$ be independent random variables such that $$P(Y_n=n)=\frac  1n, P(Y_n=0)=1-\frac 1 n .$$
Then $X_nY_n$ tends to $0$ in probability and Borel-Cantelli Lemma shows that $X_nY_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$: $\sum P(Y_n=n)=\infty$.
